# Sometimes do not work when use Esper inner join

Tags: esper

EPL is like this:

`select 
    cast(a.ReportTime,date,dateformat:'yyyy-MM-dd') as ReportTime,
    a.Source,
    aa.RequestNum,
    a.ServerTotal,
    a.ServerSucc,
    b.Total,
    b.Succ,
    NULL as DataChange_LastTime,
    c.Response 
    from IntlTotalCountEvent.win:time_batch(2 min) as aa 
    inner join A.win:time_batch(2 min) as a on aa.ReportTime=a.ReportTime and      aa.Source=a.Source 
    inner join B.win:time_batch(2 min) as b on a.ReportTime=b.ReportTime and    a.Source=b.Source 
    inner join C.win:time_batch(1 min 30 sec) as c on a.ReportTime=c.ReportTime and a.Source=c.Source`

Sometimes it works,but sometimes doesn't work,even Fields ReportTime and Source both use same datas.

Comment: Be precise while posting a question. It seems haven't even tried framing the question.

Comment: Sorry,this is my first time to post a question in stackoverflow.And my english is worst(often use translate),so read and write is a big problem for me.Forgive me~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch windows start when an event arrives. Each batch window is therefore independent and un-aligned with respect to other batch windows. If you want to align the batch windows use a context "create context Every5Sec start @now end after 2 minutes" and "win:keepall" instead of "win:batch".